# accessing server(hosted on my computer) from internet and is connected through wifi to my router

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, remote-access

I have hosted a tomcat java server on my computer(mac) and is accessible through LAN over wifi.

what i want is to access the server of my computer through global internet.

lets assume **my public ip is**: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx and
**local wifi ip** : 192.168.0.100

(i am running Tom cat server on port 8080)

please suggest the solutions for this scenario

Note:
- I'm fine with accessing server through DHCP ips
- No worries about internet speed.(i have good broadband)